# Show dot in center of map

Tags: android

I am trying to show a dot in center of map, and it should be in the center everytime whenever I move the map. I have added a point in map but when I move the map it is not in center anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();

        Path path = new Path();
        Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
        for(int i=0; i<listOfPoints.size()-2; i++)
        {
//              System.out.println(listOfPoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6()+"  "+ listOfPoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6());
            projection.toPixels(listOfPoints.get(i), p1);
            projection.toPixels(listOfPoints.get(i+1), p2);

            path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
            path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);  
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```